# time of bringing up or down an interface

Tags: command-line, scripts, interface

How can I write the time, in the following format `[dd-mm-yy/hh:mm:ss]` in a file when a interface was brought up or down? I want to store data like this,

```
[12-12-12/10:21:00] interface UP  
[14-12-12/19:11:14] interface DOWN
```

Answer (score 2):

One can access interface related logs using the `dmesg` from terminal. But the logs are not available anymore after you reboot your system. I am giving you a script that would store the interface up/down log in `~/interface_up_down.log`. You need to use this before you reboot or shutdown your system. Save the following script as `save_interface_log.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

dmesg -T | grep "link becomes ready" | grep $1 | awk -F "]" '{print $1}' | awk '{print $4}'| while read var1;
do
    echo -e "[$(date +%d-%m-%y)/$var1]\t$1\tUP" >> ~/interface_up_down.log
done
dmesg -T | grep "Link is down" | grep $1 | awk -F "]" '{print $1}' | awk '{print $4}'| while read var2;
do
    echo -e "[$(date +%d-%m-%y)/$var2]\t$1\tDOWN" >> ~/interface_up_down.log
done
```

Give the script executable permission from terminal using

```
chmod +x /path/to/save_interface_log.sh
```

**To run the script for `eth0`**

```
/path/to/save_interface_log.sh eth0
```

When you run the script it will save interface up/down info to the file in your desired format as below. I used `eth0` you can modify any other interface.

```
[14-12-13/19:08:15]    eth0    DOWN
[14-12-13/19:08:28]    eth0    UP
```